# How to create folder share without being able to read the folder contents?

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2003-r2

I encountered a problem when trying to create a folder share on an NTFS volume on a Windows 2003 R2 instance:

The account used for administration should - due to the sensitivity of the data - not be allowed to access the folder itself or the files therein. That access is to be restricted to the owner of the data.

But alas, as I found out, at least "List folder/read data" permission is required to be able to create a share!

So, to achieve my goal, I would have to either

- grant the admin account permission to read the data or
- grant the user account permission to access the containing folder to be able to create the share.

Or is there a third option I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about "real administrator" (eg: someone included into the "Administrators" group", you will have an hard time doing that.

I don't think you can prevent administrator access to some files: even if configuring the ACLs to deny access, the administrator can always *change the ACLs itself*.

Even the second approach (let the user create the subfolder by itself) is open to "curious" administrator as, again, nothing can stop a real admin from read/write any file.

If you talk about "share admin" but not really a machine-wide administrator, the second approach can work, though.